# Facebook API: How to get all data related to a post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all data related to a particular post like comments, likes, view count, etc in one API call. I can get likes by `{post-id}/likes` and comments by `/{post-id}/comments`.

How do I get all this detail in one API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/{post_id}?fields=id,message,likes,comments
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is it possible to get all fields instead of mentioning them in fields attribute?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: Since v2.4 you have to explicitly list all fields. See section "Declarative fields": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4